# How to make a DLNA android mobile application?

Tags: android, media-player, dlna

I have a task to make a DLNA android application as shown in the following video

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x5GnqvV-eu4

I have to implement Digital Media Controller and Digital media server in my application but i dont know where should i start. Is there any open source api for this??

What is the best way to achieve this goal??

Thanks in advance and yes i am a bit lost in this issue :P

Comment: you should consider updating the right answer to the one that mentions what you asked for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no api I'm aware of. You have to implement all the functionality by yourself - starting on lowest level, like handling network connections and data streaming. Also to make it comply DLNA standarts there is much more work to be done, and from my experience it's quite a lot of work.
For start you might need to register yourself as a member of DLNA (http://www.dlna.org) and then you'll be able to access all specification/requirement documentation describing how it should work.

Answer (score 17):

You could use **Cling** (Java/Android UPnP library and tools).
It's Free Software, distributed under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License.

http://4thline.org/projects/cling

See [chapter 5 "Cling on Android"](http://4thline.org/projects/cling/core/manual/cling-core-manual.html#chapter.Android) in the user manual.

Comment: Is this possible to play any online video?

Comment: @Angel it's supports UPnP MediaRenderer, based on gstreamer, so it can

Answer (score 3):

You can use CyberLink. There is a open source project on Github.[DLNA_Sample](https://github.com/CharonChui/CyberLink4Android)

Answer (score 2):

Try [Intel DLNA tools](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-software-for-upnp-technology-download-tools/)

They can create an Android app with DLNA stack instantly.

Comment: Will this work on Android? Seems to be built on on .NET framework.