# Play one multimedia content on multiple devices at the same time?

Tags: android, wifi, dlna

Can I send and show my multimedia content on two or more devices via DLNA
at the same time?

If yes how can I do it ? For example I want my tvs, tablets to play the same multimedia content of my smartphone( LG Nexus 4) at the same time.

If not, are there any other protocols(like wifi) to do this. Any approaches will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best implementation for android devices as i think streaming your multimedia content from media server, then multiple devices can play at same time

DLNA didn't have android api yet [How to make a DLNA android mobile application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589010/how-to-make-a-dlna-android-mobile-application)

for streaming

[Android video streaming example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335731/android-video-streaming-example)

http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Android-Media-Streaming-Tutorial

for android to android streming via wifi
[Live-stream video from one android phone to another over WiFi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401340/live-stream-video-from-one-android-phone-to-another-over-wifi)

Comment: Thanks for post UdayaLakmal, I need this for example I have a tablet and two smart TV (supported DLNA), when I play any multimedia file in my tablet this moment its playing on smart TVs at same time.

Comment: I found some library called cling http://4thline.org/projects/cling/ with integration help on  http://4thline.org/projects/cling/core/manual/cling-core-manual.html#chapter.Android they claim that "Cling can be used as an UPnP/DLNA library for Android"

Comment: Thanks UdayaLakmal, I know this library http://4thline.org/projects/cling, and I know more library http://www.openhome.org/wiki/OhNet, but I don't know how to play the same multimedia content of my smartphone(or tablet) on smart TVs  at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about DLNA players etc, but I have tried streaming my content via Youtube. It's very easy to set up and use.

The only thing is make sure your battery is plugged in, or as long as it does not die. Youtube live stream takes up a lot of battery.
Some Useful Links

[Youtube Guide / Link1](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2474026?hl=en)

Youtube Guide  / Link 2  support.google.com/youtube/answer/2853700?hl=en

Youtube Guide  / Link 3  support.google.com/youtube/answer/6273849?hl=en

Good Luck!

Comment: I could not make other 2 links proper links, as I don't have enough rep :(

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK, DLNA doesn't support viewing synchronized content across multiple devices.  The best solution I've found is [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) as a server streaming a video via RTSP.  Multiple devices can view the stream via any video client that supports RTSP, like VLC.  For Android devices [VLC for Android Beta](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon&hl=en) works well.

All clients viewing the stream will be synchronized.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: This provides an answer to the OP question "Play one multimedia content on multiple devices at the same time?".

Comment: I disagree. If he wanted an app he would / should have asked in http://android.stackexchange.com.